# Log in using CFHTTP

Tags: authentication, coldfusion, cfhttp

I'm trying to create a function in ColdFusion that will allow me to log in to the EA Sports Web App so I can retrieve my profile data and display it on my site.

Looking at the source code from their login page the first step just appears to be a simple login form:

```
<form method="post" id="login_form" action="https://www.ea.com/uk/football/services/authenticate/login" class="login_form" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirectUrl" value="http://www.ea.com/uk/football/fifa-ultimate-team" />
    <input type="hidden" name="failureUrl" value="http://www.ea.com/uk/football/login?failed=true&amp;redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ea.com%2Fuk%2Ffootball%2Ffifa-ultimate-team" />
    <input type="hidden" name="captchaFailureUrl" value="http://www.ea.com/uk/football/login?failed=true&amp;redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ea.com%2Fuk%2Ffootball%2Ffifa-ultimate-team" />
    <input id="email" name="email" class="text" type="text" tabindex="1" />
    <input id="password" name="password" class="text" type="password" tabindex="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="stay-signed" name="stay-signed" value="ON" checked="checked" tabindex="3" />
</form>
```

I'm using the CFHTTP request to submit the following:

```
<cfhttp url="https://www.ea.com/uk/football/services/authenticate/login" method="POST" result="myResult">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="email" value="#Variables.user#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="password" value="#Variables.password#" />
</cfhttp>
```

When I dump what's returned, the fileContent contains the following:
                 `<authenticate><success>0</success></authenticate>` which I'm assuming means that the login has not been successful.

I know I'm not giving you much to play with here but there doesn't seem to be a great deal more to trying to get the login to authenticate. Can anyone point out where I might be going wrong please?

Comment: 3 things jump out at me.  I don't know that this is the "answer" so i'll just comment.  1, you're not including all the form fields.  just because YOU don't need them doesn't mean they're not needed by the handler which in turn would result in an error.  2, this doesn't look like a real api so it's possible that EA is looking to see if the form was submitted by actual form so you may not be able to submit it remotely. lastly, the default useragent for cfhttp is "COLDFUSION", you may want to change that to a more valid browser name, I've had that stop me a couple times.

Comment: Is that the myResult variable you are dumping?

Comment: That's just the myResult.fileContent variable I was dumping but now when I add in the other form fields it brings back the content from them in the fileContent variable so I'm assuming the login is failing and it is going to the failureURL page?

Comment: how could it go to the failureURL page when you didn't include it in your cfhttpparams?

Comment: I added the other form fields as cfhttpparams after your suggestion so it's now getting the URL from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem but there are a few things to consider when you submit a form remotely.

First, is that you do not know what logic resides behind the form so you should submit EVERYTHING in the form in case the handler needs it for something.  If it expects a form field that you did not submit, an error will occur and you will not get logged in.

Second, you could technically consider your actions, although perfectly legitimate for your use, a bot or hack.  The target website could be looking to make sure the handler is actually being accessed by the form.  They could be looking at the HTTP_REFERER or they could even be doing some more fancy stuff like looking at the duration of your session because no HUMAN could submit a form in .0001 seconds.  In these cases you're likely not to get logged in at all unless you discover a flaw in their security logic.

Third, part of securing the site some logic also looks at the client to make sure you're a real browser.  The default value of the userAgent attribute is "COLDFUSION".  If the target is expecting something longer, or contains a valid browser name, the script would assume you are a bot and reject the request.  The solution for this is easy though.  Just put a good browser name in your userAgent attribute. You can get yours by dumping the cgi scope.  The problem with this is that you should maintain it some how so you're not trying to use an old browser 5 years from now and the target says 'Sorry, chum. We don't support IE6 any more...'

```
<cfhttp userAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; {...}" ...>
```

Comment: Setting the userAgent attribute seems to have solved this and I'm now able to log in.

I don't suppose you have much experience of converting PHP arrays to CF ones at all?

Comment: try first, then post another question with your code.  code conversion questions get a lot of crap.  I would recommend NOT putting the php tag on it because it'll be the CF guys that convert it and the PHP guys may be more liable to close it.

Answer (score 0):

All websites that log you in need to use cookies to achieve this as this is how they keep you logged in and maintain a session.
That cookie is then sent to the server with each subsequent page request to authenticate you as being logged in.
So you will need to emulate this with your cfhttp requests.
See this article 
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/725-Maintaining-Sessions-Across-Multiple-ColdFusion-CFHttp-Requests.htm

Comment: This is only an issue if you're trying to maintain a session. submitting a form and hitting the handler does not require you to maintain a session and will work fine unless a second cfhttp request needs something on the server from a different page. It's possible this may help but clues in his question do not point to this issue.

Comment: There are subsequent cfhttp requests that will be needed to return data I'm assuming and my first request returns two cookies that I capture and have set variables for to be passed in when I make a subsequent cfhttp request but at the moment I'm assuming that I'm not going to have any joy with subsequent requests as my initial request doesn't appear to be authenticating my account details that I pass in.